# Change root element in association picker control in Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm using Alfresco Share 4.2c and I have to change a root node of an association picker. When I change some property of my document I want that picker directly points to the folder where my document is placed (parent of my document).

My problem is how to access nodeRef of document from *association.ftl*. I think that one solution is to use *page.url.args.nodeRef*, find his parent and add pass it to parameter *rootNode*. I'm not satisfied with that because it works only if I'm on Edit metadata page and my clients also what to use popup window to manage properties which appears on click Edit Properties link.
In that case I don't have nodeRef of document in url.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to a NodeLocator fur such purposes: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/node-locator-intro.html

the [ancestor](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/node-locator-available.html) NodeLocator should be sufficient for your needs. Try the following setting in your form configuration:

```
<field id="my:association">
   <control>
      <control-param name="startLocation">{ancestor}</control-param>
   </control>
</field>
```